# Date fields and textinput in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, internationalization

I have a migration:

```
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.date :date, :null => false
    end
  end
```

And a view:

```
<%= form_for @task do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :date %>
<% end %>
```

The problems are

1. Why do I have "2011-12-23 00:00:00" instead of "2011-12-23" for records which are already in the database? In the database they are in the "2011-12-23" format.
2. How can internalize the dates so I could have dates like "12.23.11".

Comment: What database are you using? I did executed [these commands](https://gist.github.com/d5c2d25df5988b45e163), set `root :to => tasks#index`, then created a new task and everything worked as expected (i.e. no trailing 00:00:00).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you could use the value option and the i18n API/l helper. Something like :

```
<%= f.text_field :date, :value => l(@model.date) %>
```

Then in your locale file :

```
# config/locales/your_locale.yml
your_locale:
  date:
    formats:
      # Whatever format that fits your needs
      default: "%d/%m%/%Y"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a helper that will take the value and spit out something nicer

```
def prettifydate(ugly)
   return ugly.strftime('%m.%d.%Y')
end
```

In your form, take the value to be the helper method and return the pretty string.

```
<%= form_for @task do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :date, :value => prettifydate(@task.date) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: There are two problems here. First, rails already have its own smth like this helper, so it's not a good idea  to make another one. Second, it isn't good with i18n engine in rails.